# Run MongoDump / MongoRestore in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there an easy way to run these commands using the C# driver?  The only documentation I found involves running the EXE as a process etc, which seems a bit heavy.

The only related question I found was unanswered... am I missing something fundamental here?

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/127zntq9pr/mongodump-in-c

Comment: Could you just use [db.copyDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) instead? I guess I'm asking, what's the end-goal here for the application, do you need to actually get the dump and do things to it, then restore it, or are you just looking to copy the database?

Comment: No, looking to create a dump to file for backup, which then gets sent up to Amazon S3

Comment: mongodump and mongorestore are applications, not MongoDB commands which is why you would have to run the executable. If interested, the C++ code for dumping a database is here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/tools/dump.cpp#L175

Comment: Thanks @JamesWahlin, that explains a lot!  I think running the EXE is probably easier than creating my own "Mongodump" app in C#, so will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mongodump and mongorestore are applications, not MongoDB commands which is why you would have to run the executable.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately nope. I think that easier way to do regular backup of your mongodb is to write backup script and to create task in scheduler. nice answer how to do this you can find here: [MongoDB script to backup replication set locally to a Windows Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822855/mongodb-script-to-backup-replication-set-locally-to-a-windows-server)
if there are simpler solutions I'll be happy to know about them -- this problem is actual for me too. :)