# MongoDB script to backup replication set locally to a Windows Server

Tags: mongodb

I would like to make a Daily Backup of my MongoDB from a replication set running from Windows 2012 servers.

End goal would be to get a daily backup and write the backup to a remote or local share - Windows.

Can I batch the mongodump command?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 29):

Sorry, it's a bit late but the following seems to work OK for me. The script dumps the database and compresses the output using 7-Zip.

**1) Create backup script (backup.bat)**

```
@echo off

REM move into the backups directory
CD C:\database_backups


REM Create a file name for the database output which contains the date and time. Replace any characters which might cause an issue.
set filename=database %date% %time%
set filename=%filename:/=-%
set filename=%filename: =__%
set filename=%filename:.=_%
set filename=%filename::=-%

REM Export the database
echo Running backup "%filename%"
C:\mongodb\mongodump --out %filename%


REM ZIP the backup directory
echo Running backup "%filename%"
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%filename%.zip" "%filename%"


REM Delete the backup directory (leave the ZIP file). The /q tag makes sure we don't get prompted for questions 
echo Deleting original backup directory "%filename%"
rmdir "%filename%" /s /q

echo BACKUP COMPLETE
```

**2) Schedule the backup**

1. Open **Computer Management**
2. Go to **Task Scheduler** and select **Create Task**.
3. On the **General** tab, enter a description and select **Run whether user is logged on or not** if you want the task to run at night.
4. On the **Triggers** tab, select when you would like the task to run.
5. On the **Actions** tab, create a new action which points at your batch script.

Comment: If I could give you +2, I would.

Comment: Thanks for that. Just what I think is missing - the transport of the backup zip to a remote location.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running on linux, not Windows 2012, but here is what I do. On one of the servers in the replica set, this script gets run every night via a cron job.

```
#config
BACKUPNAME=[backup file name]
DATAPATH=[path to mongo data folder]

DATESTAMP=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
FILENAME=backup.$BACKUPNAME.$DATESTAMP.tar.gz
TARPATH=$DATAPATH/$FILENAME
echo $DATESTAMP;

/etc/init.d/mongod stop

/usr/bin/mongodump --journal --dbpath $DATAPATH --out $DATAPATH/backup
tar czvf $TARPATH $DATAPATH/backup
rm -rf $DATAPATH/backup
/usr/bin/s3cmd put $TARPATH s3://[backup s3 bucket name]/$FILENAME
rm -f $TARPATH

/etc/init.d/mongod start
/scripts/prunebackups
```

I'm using s3cmd to send files to an S3 bucket on Amazon AWS, but you could just as easily copy the file anywhere. `prunebackups` is a script that deletes old backups from S3 based on how old they are.

On Windows I'd create a batch file that does similar tasks. In essence:

1. Stop mongod
2. run mongodump to generate the data
3. zip up the dumped data and move it somewhere
4. clean up files
5. start mongod again

You can then use [Task Scheduler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx) to run it periodically.

If you have other mongod instances in the replica set, you shouldn't run into any issues with downtime. The backup instance in my setup is never used for reads or writes, but only for backups and in case one of the other instances goes down.

MongoDB has documentation on different backup strategies: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/

We chose the mongodump approach because for us it's cheaper to store dump backups than snapshots. This is the specific strategy we used: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-databases-with-binary-database-dumps/. Good news is, we actually had to restore data from a backup to production once and it was pretty painless.

Comment: Why would you stop and re-start the `mongod` process in order to do a `mongodump`?